# How to change attribute name in admin side magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4

How to change attribute name in admin side magento 2?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Store -> Attributes -> Product and search product name and SKU then edit and then change name as well.

See the screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Hey, 
Great BUT sorry to say i want programmatically change attribute name, And sorry for not written in the tittle.
If you know then please answer the question.

Comment: ok so do you want to change the attribute label or code programmatically?

Comment: I got the answer.                                                                                                                      Thank You for replying and your support :)